# Scala - macro-annotate method calls?

Tags: scala, macros, annotations, sbt

I'm trying to write a simple macro annotation that will let me time the method execution either every time - if I annotate the method definition - or just this one time if I annotate a method call.

Annotating method definitions works just fine. However

```
object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    @MyMacro
    doTest() //"Hello World"
  }
}
```

seems syntactically incorrect. Because intellij is complaining that after `:Unit ={` it "expects" a `}`, a warning that disappears wwhen I remove the `@MyMacro`.

What is the correct way to annotate a method call (or arbitrary expressions, for that matter)?

(e.g. I may not be interested in getting timings for all calls to `getX` but I may want to measure the time spent in it at one particular place in the code:

```
val x = @MyMacro getX()
```

)

**Update**

This works:

```
object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    hello()
  }

  @MyMacro
  def hello(): Unit ={
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
object Main {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit ={
    hello(): @MyMacro
  }

  def hello(): Unit ={
    println("Hello World")
  }
}
```

because

```
Error:(10, 15) macro annotation could not be expanded (the most common reason for that is that you need to enable the macro paradise plugin; another possibility is that you try to use macro annotation in the same compilation run that defines it)
hello(): @MyMacro
          ^
```

I'm simply compiling with `sbt`, using

```
object BuildSettings {
  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    version := "0.0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8",
    scalacOptions += "",
    crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.2", "2.10.3", "2.10.4", "2.10.5", "2.10.6", "2.11.0", "2.11.1", "2.11.2", "2.11.3", "2.11.4", "2.11.5", "2.11.6", "2.11.7", "2.11.8"),
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("releases"),
    addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
  )
}

object ScalaMacroDebugBuild extends Build {
  import BuildSettings._

  lazy val root: Project = Project(
    "root",
    file("."),
    settings = buildSettings
  ) aggregate(macros, examples)

  lazy val macros: Project = Project(
    "macros",
    file("macros"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies <+= (scalaVersion)("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _))
  )

  lazy val examples: Project = Project(
    "examples",
    file("examples"),
    settings = buildSettings
  ) dependsOn(macros)
}
```

which should take care of both issues?

Answer (score 0):

> [An annotation of an expression e appears after the expression e, separated by a colon.](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html)

So `val x = getX(): @MyMacro` should work.

Comment: Hm ... I seem to have some trouble with that (see edit above).

Comment: Maybe macro annotations on expressions just aren't supported? http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html certainly doesn't mention them: "Annotating any top-level or nested _definition_ with something that Scala recognizes as a macro will let it expand"; "apply not just to classes and objects, but to arbitrary _definitions_".

Comment: That's a shame. So I guess if I want that kind of functionallity, I'd have to look to dynamic macros?

Comment: Indeed, macro annotations can't be applied to expressions. What kind of use cases for that do you have in mind?